# python + numpy error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, math, syntax, data-conversion

Good day! I am currently converting a function from MATLAB which involves image processing. Right now I am to process an image using the 'canny' function. And now I am currently getting a 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes' to the line

```
    X = (h + (d1 + d2) / 2.0) * xscaling
```

because **'h'** is the only one that returns a different tuple size

```
 h =   (np.hstack((im[:, 2:cols], np.zeros((rows, 1)))) - np.hstack((np.zeros((rows, 1)), im[:, 1:cols-1])))
 v = (np.vstack((im[2:rows,:] , np.zeros((1,cols)))) - np.vstack((np.zeros((1,cols)), im[1:rows-1,:])))

d1 = (np.block([[im[1:rows, 1:cols], np.zeros((rows-1, 1))],
            [np.zeros((1, cols))]]) -
  np.block([[np.zeros((1, cols))],
            [np.zeros((rows-1, 1)), im[:rows-1, :cols-1]]]))
d2 = (np.block([[np.zeros((1, cols))],
            [im[:rows-1, 1:cols], np.zeros((rows-1, 1))]]) -
  np.block([[np.zeros((rows-1, 1)), im[1:rows, :cols-1]],
            [np.zeros((1, cols))]]))
```

the following variables returns values(np.shape()):

**h** = (112L, 127L)

v = (111L, 128L)

d1 = (112L, 128L)

d2 = (112L, 128L)

***Is it the composition of variable h's computation?*** Can someone please **modify** so it would have the same output to the rest of the variables?

**EDIT: VARIABLE 'v' value was (111L, 128L) not (112L, 128L)**

Comment: Yes, `h` is obviously wrong, just like it would be wrong in Matlab.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... `im` is the image, `rows` is the total number of rows in the `im` and `cols` is the total number of columns. What is the shape of `im`??

Comment: (112L, 128L) is the shape of im

Comment: EDIT: VARIABLE 'v' value was (111L, 128L) not  (112L, 128L)